# File.Readalltext stops after it detects a space

Tags: vb.net, file, encryption

Im working on a VB.NET app to encrypt text with a custom key. it writes the encrypted text to Documents\FEDS\text.txt and reads it into a textbox. For instance, if i want it to encrypt `Autism Has Become An Epidemic`, then it encrypts that into `Ãõ ë÷ýŸöúÅr´Çãûïé¯âû¸·Â»Æåùëç`
However, the command `textbox1.text = file.readalltext("Yourpathhere\text.txt")`
returns the text `Ãõ` into the Textbox, and stops after the first space. But if i make it remove the spaces from the file, it wont decrypt properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: is it possible to show me how you encrypt the text? I could try to reproduce the problem and help you out with this

Comment: Maybe the space is actually an evironment new line? You could try to check by turning the textbox with multiline = true.

Comment: A property encrypted file is not text but binary.  It is likely not reading a space but an EOF marker.  The text shown doesnt look encrypted at all, but simply Encoded somehow

Comment: You could also add ".ToString" to it
textbox1.text = file.readalltext("Yourpathhere\text.txt").ToString

Comment: @WaiFungAuYeung : That is just redundant since `File.ReadAllText()` already returns a string. It would be like doing: `"This is a string".ToString()`.

Comment: @WaiFungAuYeung textbox1 is just a richtextbox that i renamed, which are multiline by default